# Selecting item and show the price in an input field in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[screenshot for your perusal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvmVD.png)

Hi,
I am new in Angular. I have here a form group and I would like to display the price of the product that is being selected in the select dropdown menu to the left. I need to get the price of the selected item so I can multiply this to the quantity field to get the total price.
Your suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<td><select class="form-control" formControlName="firstItem">                                
                      <option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]='item.name' selected>
                       {{item.name}}
                      </option>
                  </select></td>  
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly [value]="applyForm.get('firstItem').value"></td>              
          <td><input type="number" class="form-control"  min="0" max="1000" formControlName="firstQty"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="" formControlName="firstTotal"></td>



 private list = [
{ price: 205, name: 'NLIGHTEN Premium Soap' },
{ price: 205, name: 'NLIGHTEN Kojic Papaya with Glutathione' },
{ price: 550, name: 'NLIGHTEN Facial Cleanser' }];
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to this,

```
<td>
 <select class="form-control" formControlName="firstItem">                                
  <option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item.price" selected>
   {{item.name}}
  </option>
 </select>
</td>  
<td>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly [value]="applyForm.get('firstItem').value">
</td>              
<td>
 <input type="number" class="form-control"  min="0" max="1000" formControlName="firstQty">
</td>
<td>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly value="" formControlName="firstTotal">
</td>
```

I have changed the `[value]="item.price"` in `options`. (Used double quotes `"` instead of `'`, and assigned to `item.price`).